# Django Python: How to convert datetime.time(2, 3) to String format H:M:S

Tags: python, django, datetime

In my Django models I have a `models.TimeField` to store time. When doing `model.objects.filter().values()` my `TimeField` gets return as `datetime.time(2,3)` for example. I want to return it as a string. In this case since the time is AM my string should look like `2:03:00 AM` or if PM then `2:03:00 PM`. It could also be formatted as a 24-hour format. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.strftime('%I:%H %p')` this will print as `“10:30 a.m.”`.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) you can see all the formats.

Comment: @Mikebarson happy to help ;), if you are happy with the solution mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Do you happen to know how to display dates as `Jan 01, 2001` instead of `2001-01-01`?

Comment: @Mikebarson I'm my answer there is a link to the available formats ;), for example what you asked will be "%b %d, &Y"

Comment: http://strftime.org/ is a better resource than the official docs (sadly).